# Convert lat/lng to x/y pixel 2D PNG image

Tags: python, javascript, coordinates, utm, pixel

I have a 2D PNG map which I know the corners of my image and I also have the image size all as below:

```
image size: 600x600 pixel  
top-right coordinate: (35.74706129,52.08012633) => (lat,long)  
bottom-left coordinate: (35.66569172,52.00198088) => (lat,long)
```

Also I have a lot of points in lat/long that I need to find them on my map.

How can I convert lat/long to pixel to find the exact right place of my points on the map?

[image]

i did it with calculate distance between top and bottom but i got below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it before, but it seems to me like it would be fairly straight forward math, no?

```
35.74706129 - 35.66569172 = 
0.08136957 = distance between top and bottom / 600px =
0.00013561595 = distance of one side of pixel to the other.
```

This could be much easier accomplished with bringing the image into a GIS solution such as GlobalMapper, ArcGIS, or QGIS which all offer methods to bring in images with user defined coordinates for the image corners.

Here's the step by step guide to accomplish in QGIS (opensource) GIS solution:
https://guides.lib.utexas.edu/georeference-raster-data/qgis-georeference-by-map-corners

Comment: i did it before but get wrong values.
just check my post i add the picture.

Comment: Are you looking for a routing distance solution?

Comment: no just wanna visualize some data on map like the second picture, so i'm looking for solution for mapping my points on the map pictures with i will get them from map apis like google,  mapbox and so on

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying now. The image with the colored points is the image you are attempting to georeference to the map? If this is the case, are you attempting to place the image via Python using the previously mentioned corner coordinates? Unless this is a routine that you are trying to automate w/ Python you may be better off using a software solution I mentioned above. Sorry I could not be more help.